# Trying to equally distribute elements within a div to fill space between

Tags: html, css

Trying to generate a table which will space out each piece of information equally within a div.

This is how it looks like now, I'm trying to equally space things out:
[image]

```
 <section id="databox" class="databox">
     <div id="'+cursor.value.userName +'"><span>' + 
        cursor.value.userName + '</span> | <span>' + 
        cursor.value.fn+ '</span> | <span>'+ 
        cursor.value.ln+ '</span> | <span>'+ 
        cursor.value.pw+ '</span> | <span>'+ 
        cursor.value.em+ '</span> | <span>'+ 
        cursor.value.dob+ '</span> | <span>'+
        cursor.value.tel+ '</span> | <span>'+ 
        cursor.value.scl+ '</span> | <span>'+
        cursor.value.gender+ 
        ' <input type="button" onclick="removeobject(\'' + cursor.value.userName + '\')" value="remove"/></div>'
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
  .databox{
    color:white;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
#databox div{
    text-align: justify;
}
#databox div span{
    display: inline-block;

}
.databox div:nth-child(odd){
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); 
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.databox div:nth-child(even){
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;    
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#databox div:after{
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set the `width` of spans with percentages? Like `.databox span { width: 10%; }` ?

Comment: You have tabular data, why don't you use a `<table>`?

Comment: +1 This IS tabular data. Use a [data table](http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data) (last column = Actions like "Remove") and `table-layout: fixed` + some width on each `th`, problem solved

Comment: Alright, I'll try replacing the spans and div with table tags and do it that way. But tomorrow. 6am over here, gonna sleep :/ Thanks for the advice

Comment: I did it using tables and it looks amazing. http://i.imgur.com/Bc1SLAq.png Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to ugly solutions then here is one:

http://jsfiddle.net/KBZg3/

Taking advantage of `text-align: justify`

Comment: I actually really like this solution, it's pretty simple. I'm going to try it with the table first like everyone suggested just so I can get used to them. But if it doesn't work, ill do something like you suggest. Thanks